# Nodejs always cann't capture child process's stdout data completely, unless child process fllush(stdout)

Tags: node.js, stdout, child-process, spawn

I use nodejs to captured its child process's stdout data, but always captured the former part of child process's stdout data. When I add **fllush(stdout)**，It works OK. But I don't know why, and don't want to add flush(stdout).

Here is my code:

```
var tail_child = spawn(exefile, [arg1, arg2, arg3]);
tail_child.stdin.write('msg\n');    
tail_child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {    
    console.log(data);    
});
```

child_process.c

```
printf("data\n");
```

Need your help! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `stdout` in general is buffered until a newline is written. However, if `stdout` is not a tty (which is the case here with `child_process.spawn()`), all output is buffered, regardless of newlines.

If you don't want to use `fflush()` manually, you can disable `stdout` buffering entirely by doing `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` once at the beginning of your C program.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have another question, after child process prints hanoi (4096), child process calls exit(0). The node can only print(3802). Is there a way to solve this?